# Creating android library (aar file) including Module dependency

Tags: android, dependencies, android-library, aar

I have a problem with creating aar file including dependencies. My library has two type of dependencies. The first one is jar file and the second one is the spongycastle project which is added as module in my project.
The jar file is OK but spongycastle module is not OK. when third party application call a function from aar file which uses one of spongycastle functions, it freezes. when i comment spongycastle function call from my aar file function, it works. Any one can help me to solve my problem?
my aar file gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':pkix')
    compile files('libs/ccidlib-v1.2.3.jar')
}
```

pkix gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    //compile project(':extern:spongycastle:core')
    //compile project(':extern:spongycastle:prov')
    compile project(':core')
    compile project(':prov')
    compile files('libs/ccidlib-ASR18U-v1.2.5.jar')
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
targetCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.51.0.0'
```

Core:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
targetCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.51.0.0'
```

prov:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    //compile project(':extern:spongycastle:core')
    compile project(':core')
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
targetCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.51.0.0'
```

pg:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    //compile project(':extern:spongycastle:core')
    //compile project(':extern:spongycastle:prov')
    compile project(':core')
    compile project(':prov')
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
targetCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.51.0.0'
```

Thanks in advance.

Mohsen

Comment: Could you upload the source project to test it by myself? @MohsenGorgani

Comment: thank you for your reply. I haven't permission to load my project. i solved my problem by converting my custom spongycastle to jar file and i used jar files in my android library project. but now i have to store 2 project for each version. one for my custom spongycastle project and one for my android library project.

Comment: Could you share the ccidlib-v1.2.3.jar library? @MohsenGorgani

Comment: No i can't. it is proprietary library.